# Custom painter for jTextPane not working

Tags: java, xml, styles, jtextpane, synth

I'm trying to stylize a *jTextPane* using *Java Synth* and XML. I can apply a style to *jPanes* and to *jButtons* but cannot apply to jTextPanes. The problem is that the paint method *paintTextPaneBackground* (or even paintTextPaneBorder) in my custom painter is not called.

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<synth>


    <object id="painter" class="ui.themes.MyPainter" />

    <!-- BASIC -->
    <style id="basic">
        <font name="Helvetica" size="18" />

        <state>
            <color value="#ff0000" type="BACKGROUND" />
            <color value="#000000" type="FOREGROUND" />
            <opaque value="true" />
            <insets top="12" left="12" bottom="12" right="12" />

        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="basic" type="region" key=".*" />

    <!-- PANE  -->
    <style id="panel">
        <painter method="panelBackground" idref="painter" />
    </style>
    <bind style="panel" type="region" key="Panel" />

    <!-- JBUTTON  -->
    <style id="button">
        <insets top="12" left="12" bottom="12" right="12" />
        <state>
            <color value="#212121" type="FOREGROUND" />
            <painter method="buttonBackground" idref="painter" />
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="button" type="region" key="BUTTON" />

    <!-- JTEXTPANE  -->
    <style id="textpane">       
        <insets top="12" left="12" bottom="12" right="12" />
        <state>
            <color value="#0000ff" type="BACKGROUND" />
            <color value="#212121" type="FOREGROUND" />
            <painter method="textPaneBackground" idref="painter" />
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="textpane" type="region" key="TEXT_PANE" />


</synth>
```

My custom painter:

```
    public class MyPainter extends SynthPainter {




    @Override
    public void paintButtonBackground(SynthContext context, Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        System.out.println("This method is called. :)");
    }   

    @Override
    public void paintPanelBackground(SynthContext context, Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
                System.out.println("This method is called. :)");
    }

    public void paintTextPaneBackground(SynthContext context, Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
                System.out.println("This method is NOT CALLED. :(");
    }

}
```

How can I apply a style to a jTextPane?

Comment: Let me guess... You're using Nimbus L&F ?

Comment: Not.  Just SynthLookAndFeel class: SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
        laf.load(LaFTester.class.getResourceAsStream("laf.xml"), LaFTester.class);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);